# React hook forms - Rendering next step of form not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a dynamic form in my application, which consists of multiple sections, each section has a dynamic number of form items.

Reproduce example in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vzfeyf?file=src%2Fcreate-inspection%2Findex.tsx

```
const inspectionForm = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Vehicle Basic Inspection Form',
  inspectionFormSections: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Tyre Checks',
      order: 0,
      inspectionFormItems: [
        {
          id: 1,
          label: 'Front Driver Side',
          itemType: 5,
          inspectionFormSectionId: 1,
          inspectionFormSectionName: 'Tyre Checks',
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Lights Checks',
      order: 1,
      inspectionFormItems: [
        {
          id: 5,
          label: 'Front low beam',
          itemType: 5,
          inspectionFormSectionId: 2,
          inspectionFormSectionName: 'Lights Checks',
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Now, I want the user to be able to input these values in a Form Wizard like multi-step form.
So each section would render in a new Form Step.

As I am already using React MUI, I am using the React MUI Stepper. I am also using React Context to handle the state of the form.

The issue I'm having is that in the `FormSectionComponent`, I have buttons to render next/previous sections(steps). but even though the data is updating in the `formModel` the next step is not rendering on the UI.

```
/**
 * A form section, which will be rendered in a separate step.
 * Each step is a different section within the form.
*/
const FormSectionComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { formTemplate, steps, activeStep, handleNext, handleBack } =
    useCreateInspectionState();
  console.log('formTemplate', formTemplate, 'activeStep', activeStep);

  const formModel = new CreateInspectionSectionForm(
    formTemplate?.inspectionFormSections![activeStep]!
  );

  const { control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: formModel,
    mode: 'onBlur',
  });

  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'inspectionItems',
    keyName: 'ui_id',
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <CardContent>
          <FormItems control={control} fields={fields} />
        </CardContent>
        <Divider sx={{ m: '0 !important' }} />
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={12}
              sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
            >
              {activeStep !== 0 && (
                <Button variant="tonal" color="secondary" onClick={handleBack}>
                  Previous
                </Button>
              )}
              {activeStep !== steps.length - 1 && (
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleNext}>
                  Next
                </Button>
              )}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

So even though I click Next / Previous it is always displaying the first step.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? and how do I get the next step to render and display on the UI.

Comment: I check the issue is on the fields, the fields didn't change even you click next, it's still refering to first 'Tyre Checks', it should be changed to 'Lights Checks', not sure how to change is using useFieldArray